Why doesn't Docker open the new fd for CMD?
I'm trying to redirect stdout to /dev/null after duplicating it to fd 3 (in order to throw away a third-party library's use of stdout). This works just fine in a shell script (including a shell script called from another shell script and a Python script called from a shell script). However, Docker seems to be closing fd 3, so my app can't write to it.
ubuntu$ cat run.sh 
echo No hello from me!
echo Hello from me >&3
ubuntu$ sh run.sh
No hello from me!
run.sh: line 2: 3: Bad file descriptor
ubuntu$ sh run.sh 3>&1 >/dev/null
Hello from me
ubuntu$ docker run --rm -v$PWD:$PWD -w$PWD ubuntu sh run.sh
./run: 2: 3: Bad file descriptor
No hello from me!
ubuntu$ docker run --rm -v$PWD:$PWD -w$PWD ubuntu sh run.sh 3>&1 >/dev/null
./run: 2: 3: Bad file descriptor
ubuntu$ 

I was expecting the last output to be identical to that of the redirected shell command.

That's ... not a reasonable expectation. The container doesn't run as a child of the shell command that tried to start it up -- rather, docker is a client that connects to a daemon, so file descriptors aren't inherited but rather need to be explicitly plumbed through over the wire protocol used for that connection. You wouldn't expect your fd 3 to be transported over a ssh connection, right? Same thing applies here.

Oh… same reason that it can run as root (I guess docker executable doesn't need to be setuid). Is there a good workaround? Maybe another volume and redirection inside the container? What about a named pipe?

Combining a named pipe and a volume should work, yes.

(and your guess is right: if permissions on the socket used to connect to the daemon are set up to allow access to appropriate users -- usually done with group permissions -- the docker command line tool doesn't need to be privileged).

This will redirect fd 3:
docker run --rm -v$PWD:$PWD -w$PWD ubuntu sh -c './run.sh 3>&1 >/dev/null'

after all, you want to suppress it.

One important point I left out of the original question, is that I'm trying to suppress some of the container's output. There's a login banner (NVIDIA) I don't know how to disable.
